# Boundary conditions of this problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electrostatics

We have

1. A point charge,
2. a homogeneously charged insulator with total charge $Q''$ which is a ball with radius $R$,
3. a conducting metal ball with charge $Q'$, radius $R$ and a grounded metal (no charge).

The things I named are all separated by vacuum. I am supposed to identify the boundary conditions. Does anybody know how to do this? The only thing I know is that the potential inside the grounded metal is zero.

Comment: Safe to assume that the point charge is $Q$?

Comment: Yes, I could live with that ;-)

Comment: Is this for an exam? 400 bounty points?

Comment: no, i just want to understand the concept of boudary conditions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have three boundaries:

1. at infinity
2. at the surface of the conducting sphere
3. at the surface of the insulator.

I'd set the potential at infinity to be zero; otherwise it depends on the radius $R$ of the conducting sphere and on the geometry of the charges, which is strange to me.  You can add a constant offset everywhere if you prefer that.

The potential at the surface of the conducting sphere is a constant.

Let's assume the insulator is a linear dielectric with permeability $\epsilon$.  The potential at its boundary is continuous $V_\text{insulator} = V_\text{vacuum}$, and 
$$
\epsilon \frac{\partial V_\text{insulator}}{\partial r}
=
\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial V_\text{vacuum}}{\partial r}
$$
at its surface (where $r$ is the distance from the center of the insulating sphere).

If you actually needed to find the potential in the vacuum, you'd need to add the three monopole fields $V_i = kQ_i/|\vec r - \vec r_i|$ and do some multipole expansion at the sphere surfaces, which would require you to know the actual geometry.  See Griffiths's examples 3.8 and 4.7.

Comment: Thank you, I just have a few questions about this: What do you mean that $\varepsilon V$ is smooth? Does this mean that we also have at the boundary of the insulator $\varepsilon V_{\insulator} = \varepsilon_0 V_{\vacuum}$? How would I treat the homogenous charge of the insulator and the charge of the metal? So I have the boundary conditions: $\phi \rightarrow 0 , r \rightarrow \infty$, the potential and its first derivative are continous at the surface of the insulator. the potential is constant over the whole volume of the conducting sphere and zero over the grounded sphere.

Comment: but so far, what i would be looking for in the multipole expansion so that I adjust the charges appropriately? Btw, you don't need to do this explicitely, I am just hypothetically interested in this problem and thanks for your answer so far.

Comment: @Lipschitz I suppose "$\epsilon V$ is smooth" was a confusing statement, so I removed it.  You will *not* have the same potential at the conducting sphere and at infinity, unless the total charge is zero. I refer you again to a good textbook for a worked example of the multipole expansions to find the field everywhere.  If you only had two charges there'd be a natural axis of symmetry, but with three charges the geometry makes a big difference.

Comment: he problem is that this example is not covered in most textbooks due to its complexity. My question is just: What limits would I have to consider due to the charges? (I also did not find a full answer to this in Griffith's book)

Comment: @Lipschitz I'm not sure what you mean by "what limits." If your problem is "state the boundary conditions" you are done. If your problem is "find the fields" you require the geometry of the charges. For all but the most magical of charge geometries I'd expect that the simplest way to find real fields is by numerically solving the Laplace equation (with a source term in the insulator).

Comment: sorry, one more question: Your condition of the electric field between a dielectric and the surrounding is only referring to the normal component $n$ of the surface, as you are just saying what $\varepsilon \langle \nabla V, n \rangle = \varepsilon_0 \langle \nabla V, n \rangle $ is. What about the tangential component of the electric field?

Comment: Tangential fields must satisfy the conditions of $\nabla\times\vec D$ as determined by Maxwell's equations.